# Wait for code to complete using await/async and promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I am trying to use await/async along with Promise.all to get some arrays and then move on with the code but when I simulate a delay in the code it appears to not be working. My code is below

```
    async getAllTheUnits() {
        // get all units
        console.log('allunits called 1')
        let unitRef = db.collection('units')
        try {
            let allUnitsSnapShot = await unitRef.get()
            await Promise.all(allUnitsSnapShot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
                let u = doc.data()
                u.id = doc.id
                await this.allOfTheUnits.push(u)
            }))
            console.log('allunits called 2 ', this.allOfTheUnits.length)
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('Error getting all the units', err);
        }
    },
    async getAllTheWeeks() {
        // get all weeks
        console.log('allweeks called 1')
        let weekRef = db.collection('weeks')
        try {
            let allWeeksSnapShot = await weekRef.get()
            await Promise.all(allWeeksSnapShot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
                let w = doc.data()
                w.id = doc.id
                await this.allOfTheWeeks.push(w)
            }))
            console.log('allweeks called 2 ', this.allOfTheWeeks.length)
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('Error getting all the weeks', err);
        }
    },
```

Here is a simplified function where I call these other functions

```
    async initUsersCourse() {

        console.log('1')

        await this.getAllTheUnits()
        await this.getAllTheWeeks()

        console.log('2')

        const allUnits = this.allOfTheUnits
        const allWeeks = this.allOfTheWeeks

        console.log('3')
        console.log('allUnits ', Array.isArray(allUnits), allUnits.length   )
        console.log('allWeeks ', Array.isArray(allWeeks), allWeeks.length)
    }
```

As stated above. If I put in a `settimeout` in the `getAllTheWeeks` function to simulate a delay the `initUsersCourse` function does not wait and moves on to `console.log('2')`

Comment: You need to `await Promise.all...` to have the parent `initUsersCourse` wait for the promise to finish. There is no `setTimeout` in your code. `setTimeout` does not work with async/await out of the box, look up how to make a promise out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function must return a promise, you need resolve the promise after the timeout finish :

```
async getAllTheWeeks() {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, 2000 ) );
}
```

for your specific code problem, *Promise.all* want an array of promise, so the function you give at your *allWeeksSnapShot.docs.map* must return a promise, that's not currently the case so *promise.all* must return directly

Comment: This is working. Can you show me how to incorporate it inside my existing function please. I am pulling what little hair I have left out :)

Comment: @Jason But the question was how to simulate a delay with getAllTheWeeks instead of real asynchronous ops, wasn't it? That's how, this is ready to use code

Comment: @r043v allWeeksSnapShot.docs.map returns a promise, this is guaranteed by the use of `async` as a callback

Comment: @EstusFlask I was only simulating a delay to test the code. In reality I just want these two functions ```await this.getAllTheUnits()```
        ```await this.getAllTheWeeks()```
to run before the rest of the code runs

Comment: @EstusFlask yes, but he seem to await an array push and not the real job, so it need await/return doc.data() or his job is not really async ?

Comment: @r043v I am open to a better way to write this code. I am here to learn form you guys. :)

Comment: @Jason if the real async job is "doc.data()" you must return it, you actually return "this.allOfTheWeeks.push(w)" who seem to be an no async array push, so promise.all await all your array push and not your real jobs

Comment: @r043v The problem I was facing was if the user's browser had a hiccup or the server had an issue the init function would keep running even if these two functions failed ```await this.getAllTheUnits() await this.getAllTheWeeks()``` I am just trying to protect against this

Comment: @r043v Didn't notice await data, yes, makes sense, no need for Promise.all here but this depends on what's really happens here (looks like it's firebase)